# Ошибка при создании миграции Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Понятно что параметр `connectionString` не может быть пустым. Но вот только он вроде не пустой.

Код *appsettings.json*

```json
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SPTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
}
```

Код *Startup.cs*

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Ввожу *Add-Migration*, Затем ввожу имя и вылетает ошибка. Что не так?

Comment: `Configuration.GetConnectionString("Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString")`

Comment: Так тозже не работает, хз почему не видет строку. Добавил просто ```options.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = SPTest; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true"));```Так заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) метод `GetConnectionString(name)` является сокращением для `GetSection("ConnectionStrings")[name]`.

То есть вам надо либо сменить конфиг на

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SPTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Либо использовать другой метод

```
Configuration.GetValue<string>("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString")
```